# Read from stdin in C++

Tags: c++, stdin

Here is my code:

```
...
...
do
{
    cin >> command;

    switch(command)
    {
        case 'i':
            cin >> key >> nome >> idade >> endereco;
            count++;

            pessoas = (Pessoa **) realloc(pessoas, count*sizeof(Pessoa *));
            pessoas[count-1] = new Pessoa(key, nome, idade, endereco);

            bTree->add(pessoas[count-1]);
            break;

        case 's':
            cin >> key;

            toSearch = (Pessoa *) bTree->search(key);

            if(toSearch == NULL)
            {
                cout << "-1" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << key << endl;
                cout << toSearch->getNome() << endl;
                cout << toSearch->getIdade() << endl;
                cout << toSearch->getEndereco() << endl;
            }

            break;

        case 'e':
            done = true;
            break;
    }

} while(!done);
...
...
```

I have a "menu" that when I enter `i`, it will insert in BTree, `s` will search and `e` will exit the program.

The problem is, when I hit `i` to insert, I have to give four parameters:

1. (int) Key;
2. (string) Name;
3. (int) Age;
4. (string) Address;

When I give a name that have an `e` character inside (eg. "James"), it will exit the program.

How do I avoid `command` to read the stdin buffer while I'm reading it on switch?

Sample input:

```
i
1
Joao da Silva 1
11
Rua 2, 3
i
2
Joao da Silva 2
12
Rua 4, 6
s
1
s
7
e
```

Thanks.

Comment: Any reason you don't use `std::vector` for `pessoas`?

Comment: Is that anything to do with my question?
Why waste stack if I need only a realloc?

Comment: Haven't found any error yet, was only wondering why you don't write idiomatic C++ there.

Comment: Is `command` a `char`?

Comment: yes, command is a char

Comment: "Is that anything to do with my question? Why waste stack if I need only a realloc?" --- (1) this has nothing to do with the question, (2) the claim about "wasting stack" makes not a lick of sense. Just always use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

How about [`std::basic_istream::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) (definition 1)?

That would make your switch statement start as follows.

```
do
{    
    switch(cin.get())
    {
```

Bear in mind it may be prudent to check for [`std::char_traits::eof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/eof) early in your `switch` in the general case (though it shouldn't be necessary for stdin).

Comment: That would likely be the EOF case. Using `<` in the shell is comparable to binding stdin to a file, so EOF is an issue.

Comment: Maybe because I'm using spaces on `cin` ?

Comment: That could also do it. Could you add a description of your input file to the original post?

Comment: I think this needs to be split into a different question. `cin.get()` fixes your original question. The remaining issues you have relate to newline being a character and spaces causing string breaks with cin. I recommend looking into getline.

Comment: Sorry, can't accept... it didn't fixed my problem.. When I hit something that isn't `i`, `e`, `s`, it will enter in an infinite loop.

Comment: That's not a problem with cin.get(). It reads one character from the input stream regardless of what that input is. I recommend checking what you're doing with those characters, and possibly adding a `case` for `std::char_traits::eof` and `'\n'`. It might also be useful to have a `default` clause, though the example as written does not require one.

Answer (score -1):

Done using `fgetc`:

```
...
...
while(!done)
{
    cin >> command;

    switch(command)
    {
        case 'i':
            scanf("%d\n", &key);

            strCounter = 1;
            while(true)
            {
                buff = fgetc(stdin);

                // until the user types '\n'
                if(buff == '\n')
                {
                    nome[strCounter-1] = '\0';
                    break;
                }

                // realloc it
                nome = (char *) realloc(nome, (strCounter)*sizeof(char));
                nome[strCounter-1] = buff;
                strCounter++;
            }

            scanf("%d\n", &idade);

            strCounter = 1;
            while(true)
            {
                buff = fgetc(stdin);

                // until the user types '\n'
                if(buff == '\n')
                {
                    endereco[strCounter-1] = '\0';
                    break;
                }

                // realloc it
                endereco = (char *) realloc(endereco, (strCounter+1)*sizeof(char));
                endereco[strCounter-1] = buff;
                strCounter++;
            }

            count++;

            pessoas = (Pessoa **) realloc(pessoas, count*sizeof(Pessoa *));
            pessoas[count-1] = new Pessoa(key, nome, idade, endereco);

            bTree->add(pessoas[count-1]);

            break;

        case 's':
            cin >> key;

            toSearch = (Pessoa *) bTree->search(key);

            if(toSearch == NULL)
            {
                cout << "-1" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << key << endl;
                cout << toSearch->getNome() << endl;
                cout << toSearch->getIdade() << endl;
                cout << toSearch->getEndereco() << endl;
            }

            break;

        case 'e':
            done = true;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
...
...
```